# index.html is loaded but css and js urls not found (404) / working great locally

Tags: node.js, reactjs, ubuntu, nginx, path

I am stuck with a path problem I cannot solve even after I had spent 3 hours searching on Stack Overflow and google, trying everything with no success. I am sorry if I walked nearby the solution elsewhere without seeing it, please notice that I really tried.

So, my project is a backend Node JS, front React on an ubuntu 22.04 Nginx server (digital ocean).
My server is really simple :

```
// main.js

const Port_TCP = 3005;

const express = require('express'); 
const path = require("path");

let app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.set('port', Port_TCP);


app.get("*", function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/public/index.html'))
})

app.listen(Port_TCP);
```

And the public/index.html file :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>My website</title>
    <link href="css/app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="imgs/ico.png">
</head>
<body>
    <!-- React root DOM -->
    <div id="MainRouter"></div>
    <!-- React JS -->
    <script type="application/javascript" src="js/app.js" defer></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Problem is this :

- On my localhost (windows), I have no problem, website is running as it should.
- On my server (ubuntu), the website is reached, the index.html is loaded, but every url inside it are wrong and throw me classic 404 errors :

> GET https://my-website.com/css/app.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not
> Found)
>
> GET https://my-website.com/js/app.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

(tab icon is not found either)

edit - strange thing, on the server I can delete the app.get("*"...) part and I still reach the page. If I do that on localhost, got a 502...

My project folders and file set up is this :

```
/main.js (server)
/mix-manifest.json
/package.json
/package-lock.json
watcher.js (for nodemon)
webpack.mix.js
/js and /sass folder (which contain react project)
/public/
/public/index.html
/public/css/app.css
/public/js/app.js
/public/imgs/
```

edit - My NGinx configuration in etc/sites-available is :

```
server {

        root /var/www/mywebsite.fr/public;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name mywebsite.fr www.mywebsite.fr;

        location / {
               proxy_pass http://localhost:3005;
               proxy_http_version 1.1;
               proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
               proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
               proxy_set_header Host $host;
               proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
               try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

    listen [::]:443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite.fr/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite.fr/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}
server {
    if ($host = www.mywebsite.fr) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = mywebsite.fr) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name mywebsite.fr www.mywebsite.fr;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

If you can give me a lead it would be amazing.

Comment: Hello, what is your current nginx configuration ?

Answer (score 0):

It's because of relative path is not correct.
In develop and build may a bit different of relative path.
In reactjs directory, file `package.json`
modify or add `homepage` it could be help:

- `"homepage": "file:///android_asset/",` (for android)
- `"homepage": ".",` (for android and windows, iOS not tested)
- if above not working change homepage value to your `public` folder path

Comment: I tried the three solutions, none of them worked :/